# RemoveEldestEntry in LinkedHashmap while trying to implement LRU algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, lru

I have this code and I want to understand how it works.

```
public class LRUAlgoCacheImpl<K,V> implements IAlgoCache<K,V>{

    private int capacity;

    private LinkedHashMap<K,V> lhm;
    public LRUAlgoCacheImpl(int capacity) {
        lhm = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(capacity+1,1.1f, true) {
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
                return lhm.size()> capacity;
            }
        };      
        this.capacity=capacity;
    }
```

I understand that it overrides the `removeEldestEntry` in the `LinkedHashMap` class,but i don't quite understand how.
I could extend `LinkedHashmap` in my class declaration without doing so and just doing regular override, but I'm trying to learn more.
Could someone explain this to me please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `LRUAlgoCacheImpl` implements a LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm by applying the OO design concept of [`composition`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) with an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends a `LinkedHashMap` in order to override `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry)` to be able to evict the oldest entry when the size of the map exceeds the provided capacity.

**Why applying Composition over Inheritance?**

The main reason is related to the fact that in Java you can extend only one class unlike C++ for example so if you choose class `Inheritance` you could face design issues later if you need to make your code evolve. On the other side `Composition` makes you implement interfaces which is a good design practice and as you can implement as many interfaces as you want, the `Composition` approach is much more flexible and so a better choice for maintainability.

Comment: Hi ,thank you for your comment.I havent understood the syntax itself,i mean,during the new object declaration i open parentheses and override function ?
what does it mean?thank you in advance

Comment: It is an anonymous inner class, check the link in my answer